# Sou Inciante , e estou com um problema com uma questão, na parte de instanciar os objetos

Tags: java

7. Crie uma classe Cliente, considerando que esta deva possuir :
   Construtor 
   Deve ter o construtor padrão e um construtor que deve possuir como parâmetro somente o código do Cliente.

**Atributos**
•   Código do Cliente
•   Nome Completo

**Métodos**
•   Inserção do nome do cliente
•   Retorna do nome do cliente
•   Retorna Código do Cliente

Depois Crie um programa que instancie dois objetos Cliente, atribua o valor ao atributo Nome do Cliente. Antes e após a atribuição, imprima o Nome do Cliente utilizando a função de retorno.

A minha dúvida é quando ele diz : **"Antes e após a atribuição, imprima o Nome do Cliente utilizando a função de retorno."**, como assim imprimir o nome antes da atribuição?

**Meu código:**

**Classe Cliente**

```
package Questao7;

public class Cliente {

    int codigo;
    String nome ;

    //contrutor com o parâmetro código
    public void Cliente(int codigo){

    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;                        
    }

    public int getCodigo(){
        return codigo;

    }       
}
```

**Instanciando os objetos no Método Main, Está incompleto por causa da minha
dúvida:**

```
package Questao7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste04 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        Cliente c1= new Cliente();
        Cliente c2= new Cliente();
    }
}
```

Comment: Faltou o setCliente() no seu modelo Cliente. Então, antes de você atribuir o dado que o "usuário" vai digitar, dê um system.out.print.

Comment: Eu coloquei o setCliente(), mas aonde eu vou dar um  system.out.print exatamente?, vc pode me exemplificar com o código?, assim fica meio difícil pra entender , sou iniciante kkk

Comment: posso sim, eu to fazendo aqui uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo dessa forma:

```
public class Cliente {
    Integer codigo;
    String nome;

    //Quando se tem um contrutor sem ser vazio, precisa criar um vazio, para poder diferenciar
    public Cliente() {

    }

    // contrutor com o parâmetro código
    public Cliente(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insira um nome: " );
        String nome = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Seu nome é:" + nome);
        Cliente c1 = new Cliente();
        c1.setNome(nome);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Imprimir* nesse sentido, provavelmente se refere à função `System.out.print()`. Exemplo:

```
System.out.print(c1.getNome());
```

Comment: Obg amigos., valeu msm!